Not able to run tests on playwright using browserstack in localhost, as localhost is not working
I am trying to run playwright tests against localhost on browserstack.
I am not sure if the localhost is up, and if its up why playwright is not running the tests
My browserstack yml is as:
userName:
accessKey
platforms:
  -os:OS X
   osVersion:Sonoma
   browserName:playwright-chromium
   browserVersion:latest

My action.yml is as
jobs:
  set-environment:
  browserstack env setup
  Browserstack local tunnel setup
  Checkout repo
  Build (this will get localhost running as per expectations)
  setup node.js env
  run playwright tests

I get the error when I run tests on github actions'
post connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8000


Try setting browserstackLocal as true in the BrowserStack.yml file and to make sure that the browserstack local is running you can check localhost:45454 and see if the UI loads.

This is for running on github actions not on my local machine
